# Implementing W-buffering in modern GPU

Tags: opengl, 3d, depth-buffer

I was trying to figure out how perspective projection matrix works, and somehow I ended up in this rabbit hole of depth buffer precision.

It seems to be some interest in a depth buffer where the precision is evenly distributed through the visible space, so people started using 32 bits float depth buffers in range [0, 1], where 0 is the farthest and 1 is the closest, as described in [this article](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/depth-precision-visualized).

Some old sources also talk about W-buffer, where the visible space is evenly spread in a 16 or 24 bits integer buffer, but they also say that it is inefficient and lacks hardware support.

But in modern OpenGL and hardware, what prevents me from using a 32 bits integer buffer and write in `gl_FragDepth` some value that, when divided by W, will yield a linear distribution of the visible space in the integer depth buffer? And, if it works, why it is worse than using float?

Comment: Writing depth from your shader can prevent some GPU optimizations that allow the depth test to run before the fragment shader. This can be a significant performance impact.

Comment: Compared to using classical integer depth buffer I understand, but what about compared to floating point depth buffer?

Comment: Doesn't matter, it's the act of writing depth that causes it, not the format.